# way to override the operators? (to create rough compiler)

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example, if I wanted to do instead of

> 1 + 1 = 2

it would be something like

> "+" = print("add %d %d" % (a, b))

which would be interpreted as

> 1 + 1 = "add 1 1"

I want to use this in using python as a container to hold the logic, and then easily convert that to another language (proprietary language called huff which is akin to assembly on the ethereum virtual machine)

Comment: The behavior of the operators is dependant on the objects that are given to them. You would need to wrap the data in some wrapper class and override the behavior in the wrapper.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, so that would be painful unfortunately. For `+` specifically, you'd need to write a `__add__` method in a class to change the behaviour. Note too that you'll run into a snag when dealing with `=`/`mov` translations (I'm assuming your target language has a `mov`-like operation). You can't override the behavior of assignment, so that'll be another issue. You might need to think about this from another  angle and use the `ast` module to parse Python, then manually translate that AST to your target language.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it's not allowed to ask for code here, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since  Python does not allow overriding attributes of built-in types:

```
int.__add__ = lambda self, other: 'add {} {}'.format(self, other)

TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'
```

You will have to implement your own class to serve as a wrapper for `int`.

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        # TODO handle the case the condition is false
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return 'add {} {}'.format(self, other)

x = MyInt(1) + MyInt(2)
print(x)
# add 1 2
```

The check can be changed to the more lenient `issubclass(other.__class__, int)` which will allow the right operand to be a "normal" integer:

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        # TODO handle the case the condition is false
        if issubclass(other.__class__, int):
            return 'add {} {}'.format(self, other)

x = MyInt(1) + 2
print(x)
# add 1 2
```

Then you may also want to implement `__radd__` to at least get an associative operation:

```
class MyInt(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        # TODO handle the case the condition is false
        if issubclass(other.__class__, int):
            return 'add {} {}'.format(self, other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        # TODO handle the case the condition is false
        if issubclass(other.__class__, int):
            return 'add {} {}'.format(other, self)

x = 2 + MyInt(1)
print(x)
# add 2 1
```

Comment: Ideally I could just override it without having the call the class itself. This is to improve readability

Comment: @Alita You can't. Python does not allow overriding attributes of built-in types. `int.__add__ = lambda self, other: 'add {} {}'.format(self, other)` `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'`

Comment: If you really want to override built-in methods there's always the `forbiddenfruit` module.

Comment: @Axe319 from its pypi page: `"but it may lead you to hell if used on production code"` need I say more?

Comment: Not really, lol @DeepSpace I would never use it personally, but it is what they asked for.

Comment: @Axe319 Any way I don't think it's working in this case. `curse(int, '__add__', lambda self, other: '{} {}'.format(self, other))`, `1 + 1` still returns `2`

Comment: @DeepSpace I tried manually defining an `__add__` function earlier  `def __add__(self, other):  return f'add {self} {other}'` and then using `curse(int, '__add__', __add__)` and it worked ok. Maybe it doesn't work with lambdas? But it should.

Comment: notably, this is mainly meant as a proof of concept. A more robust solution will be developed if it turns out to be useful. i.e. forbidden fruits is fine (if it worked, lol).